# Программирование NFC

Tags: nfc, java

Здравствуйте.
Хочу реализовать такую штуку. Знаю, что это не целесообразно и некому не нужно - просто хочу узнать возможно ли это вообще и если возможно, то как лучше?

Смысл в том, чтобы Компьютер, точнее ОС, при запуске просила пользователя не пароль ввести, а предоставить, например, его телефон, в котором есть NFC.

Итого имеем компьютер, имеем подключенный к нему NFC-Reader.

То есть необходимо написать приложение, которое до загрузки основной системы будет простить эдакую аутентификацию... (типо USB-ключ,но только телефон, который всегда с собой и не надо никуда ничего втыкать и вводить, NFC же)

Так вот как это должно происходить?

1) Возьмем например java(хотя в окне выбора пользователя наверно не получиться запустить java-приложение, или я не прав?). Так вот, отыскал я [API.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/)
По моему java прекрасно работает со смарт-картами(вроде бы одно и тоже что и NFC). Когда пользователь кладет свой телефон на NFC-reader, срабатывает слушатель в программе обрабатывает событие  и предоставляет пользователю доступ или привилегии, ну не суть важна.

2) NFC подрозумевает обмен данными. В чем главный вопрос?
Телефон с NFC какие данные и как и может ли вообще оправлять на NFC-Reader, и возможно ли их потом оттуда считать???
Например, с NFC метки телефон считывает, но не посылает данные на NFC-метку.
Я же под данными подразумеваю хоть какая-нибудь маленькую строчку, например SN или MAC телефона, который однозначно идентифицирует владельца в системе компьютера.
Например есть БД, полученная строка по NFC-каналу приложением отправлятся в БД, как-нибудь еще обрабатывается и приложение получает ответ с инструкциями что делать, пользователь видит результат на экране(пошел вон - добро пожаловать).

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

P.S: При публикации ругался, что нет меток NFC...

Comment: Да, наверное можно, но только придётся везде *NFC-Reader* подключать.

Comment: В смысле везде? Вы это предполагаете в масштабе корпорации?
Я никакой коммерческой выгоды из этого не хочу получить.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы хотите по сути глубоко вмешаться в работу системы. Ваш код для этого должен быть глубоко системно-зависимым. Боюсь, Java — неподходящий инструмент для вашей задачи, вам придётся писать на голом WinAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, я не совсем понимаю вопрос.

1. Есть на стороне десктопа NFC Reader + некое API для работы с NFC - [например смотрим здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866737/applying-nfc-in-java-any-existing-api-or-libraries)
2. На стороне Android мобильника [тоже есть API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html) для работы с NFC
3. Есть понимание, что NFC это некий протокол, который умеет слать/получать биты/байты

Ну и пишите обе стороны, определите правила, протокол и вперед. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: А Windows API позволит заблокировать учётную запись до тех пор пока через какой-то сервер сообщение не придёт?

Comment: Да хз... - не силен в возможностях Windows API